# C, Objective-C preprocessor output

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to get pre-processed **C**/Objective-C code? I have some files I acquired and would like to see the code produced by some #defines.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the command line, `gcc -E foo.m` will show you the preprocessed output (just as it does for normal C/C++ files).  Of course, this will also expand any `#include` or `#import` statements you may have in your code.

Answer (score 23):

From within Xcode:

- Xcode 3: Select the file, then **Build → Preprocess**.
- Xcode 4: Select the file, then **Product → Generate Output → Generate Preprocessed File**.

Comment: Just a note - When you generate the preprocessed file this way, there is a **whole lot of** other code from the files that were #imported. The file you really want to see is at the very bottom of the output.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `-E` command-line argument to `gcc` or `clang`. This is documented as: “Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link” and indeed it outputs the preprocessed version to `stdout`.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 5: **Select the *.m file, then Product -> Perform Action -> Preprocess "*.m"**