# How to get Preprocessor Output in iOS Project？

Tags: ios, gcc, c-preprocessor

I want to get Preprocessor Output from my iOS project which was complied using LLVM GCC 4.2 because I want to do some static analysis.

I try to use flag -save-temps , but compilation fails at the precompiled header.

What else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Gcc has a command lind flag '-E' to get the prepocessed information. In xcode you can easily do with GUI. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823180/c-objective-c-preprocessor-output) for more info.

Comment: I have hundreds of source files , that command only for one file.

Comment: So you want for all the files ?. you can write a shell script to perform the same operation for all files in your project folder.

Comment: I have to a lot of work because my project also some marco for condition preprocess.