# How do I limit the scope of the preprocessing definitions used?

Tags: objective-c, c, gcc, macros, clang

How do I preprocess a code base using the clang (or gcc) preprocessor while limiting its text processing to use only #define entries from a single header file?

This is useful generally: imagine you want to preview the immediate result of some macros that you are currently working on… without having all the clutter that results from the mountain of includes inherent to C.

Imagine a case, where there are macros that yield a backward compatible call or an up-to-date one based on feature availability.

```
#if __has_feature(XYZ)
#   define JX_FOO(_o) new_foo(_o)
#   define JX_BAR(_o) // nop
...
#else
#   define JX_FOO(_o) old_foo(_o)
#   define JX_BAR(_o) old_bar(_o)
...
#endif
```

A concrete example is a collection of Objective-C code that was ported to be ARC-compatible (Automatic Reference Counting) from manual memory management (non-ARC) using a collection of macros (https://github.com/JanX2/google-diff-match-patch-Objective-C/blob/master/JXArcCompatibilityMacros.h) so that it compiles both ways afterwards.

At some point, you want to drop non-ARC support to improve readability and maintainability.

Edit: The basis for getting the preprocessor output is described here: [C, Objective-C preprocessor output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823180/c-objective-c-preprocessor-output)

Edit 2: If someone has details of how the source-to-source transformation options in Xcode are implemented (Edit > Refactor > Convert To…), that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a stupid solution, but it works: apparently you can use AppCode’s refactoring to delete uses of a macro.

This limits the solution to OS X, though. It also is slightly tedious, because you have to do this manually for every `JX_FOO()` and `JX_BAR()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the file from scratch or all the includes are in one place, why not wrap them inside of:

```
#ifndef MACRO_DEBUG
    #include "someLib.h"
    /* ... */
#endif
```

But as I mentioned, this only works when the includes are in consecutive lines and in the best case, you are starting to write the file yourself from scratch so you don't have to go and look for the includes.

Comment: If I were to do that for my macros, it would result in the opposite of what I want. If I do it for all non-macro file includes, the sources will get messy and the result still contains all the implicitly included headers (even if I temporarily go that route).

Comment: There is no other pure C way that I know of. Maybe make a file which only includes other files, put all includes there and then include it inside of `#ifndef ... #endif` (or just comment out the include of that file when needed).

Comment: I don’t actually need a way using C. What I need is a way to (mis-)use the C preprocessor in a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for sed/awk. However there exists an even better tool available for the exact use-case that you mention. Checkout [**coan**](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/).

To pre-process a source file as if the symbol `<SYMBOL>`is defined,

```
$ coan source -D<SYMBOL> sourcefile.c
```

Similarly to pre-process a source file as if the symbol `<SYMBOL>`is NOT defined,

```
$ coan source -U<SYMBOL> source.c
```

Comment: coan looks exactly like what I had in mind! I will check it out and report back. :)

Comment: I have tried to build coan on OS X, but have run into problems. Once those are cleared up, I will give coan a go.

Comment: @JanX2 I am the maintainer of coan. I don't maintain it for OS X but there are OS X users. One of them informed me recently that to build v5.1.2 for OS X 10.8 he had to: "Change AM_CXXFLAGS to -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++; Set CPP11_HAVE_MATURE_UNIQUE_PTR to 0."

Comment: Great! I will try that. I sent you an email with details (to clan@…). Apparently, you didn’t get it!

Comment: @JanX2 No I don't have such an email address. Typo for coan@...? You can use my SO email.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Yeah. I sent it to “coan@…” That was auto-correct speaking. It’s a bit too aggressive. BTW: I can’t see your SO email.

Comment: @JanX2 Ah, it's private I guess. Makes sense. Don't know what happened to your other, anyway use imk@...

Comment: OK. Resent the emails to “imk@burr….com”.